# Dynamically adding data to divs with SQL?

Tags: sql, dynamic, e-commerce

A little background first, recently began coding and I decided to take the "learn as you go" approach as this is solely a project. I have a pretty good handle of HTML and CSS, I have an understanding of Jquery, and haven't even begun to look at other languages.

So basically I'm making a suedo-e-commerce site, and I'm trying to create a page layout comprising of several divs stacked together (think standard catalog page) Creating the modules and every static with HTML and CSS, but I want to add the content, comprising of a banner and some text blocks, dynamically from a database. Now, I'm pretty sure that I will have to use SQL and reference each entry with the HTML, but I have no idea how to do that or where to even start. So I'm asking if someone could point me in the right direction with some reading material, or some examples would be awesome.

Comment: You need to learn server side language to do that buddy. All you have learnt like HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT are all client side or browser side language.  you need to learn php, asp, node etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of databases (MySQL, MSSQL etc.) to save data. In order to show data from database you need to use one of background/server side programming languages. For start I would suggest that you try with php.

[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) is good starting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simplified and I hope not condescending.  Consider separating how you collect your data and you present your data (the 'view layer').  SQL will help you pull / organize your data, and you could just string functions to add formatting (e.g. div's) to it, but you are better off investigating templating HTML.  What happens when you want to put this data into a ul list or something?  You have to re-write your perfectly good SQL.    Again, very broadly, pull data (with SQL, PHP, combination), ( or get it from a URL with javascript), into a data structure, then within a loop in your template, add the dives for each element.

Good reading really depends on which platform you'll be developing this in.   There are a bazillion alternatives, including many in Javascript, PHP, Ruby, Python, Go, ASP.    Since you mention SQL, you must have some data somewhere (rather than a data service) so you'll need a server-side language,  and since you are a beginner, you may want to look into PHP which I think is approachable.   Within that there are several PHP frameworks for data, and several for templating, and several with both.  Many of the full frameworks (in any language) are geared for experienced web devs.  That said, I like the twig templating language for PHP

This, I think, is a good place to start http://www.phptherightway.com along with the super popular but basic W3schools.  The link above I think organizes the concept a little better.

You can install the stuff you need on your laptop for that standard (and old school) 'LAMP stack', or use one of the many hosting companies, nearly all of which provide everything you need.   good luck learning!